# c++ program ends after checking p!=NULL condition (p is a pointer)

Tags: c++, pointers

The program ends with no error message, it happens after at the line while(p!=NULL) I used some console messages to figure out that it stops working there.

```
void refreshOnDataEntry(set<string> s, Node **front, Node **rear, set<set<string>> &currentSolution, set<string> &kSetUnion)
{
    set<string> currentShare;
    set<string>::iterator it;
    Node *p = *front;
    Node *data = new Node;
    data->S = s;
    data->unique = s;
    cout << "I'm about to die" << endl;
    while (p!=NULL)
    {
        currentShare = setIntersection(p->unique, data->unique);
        p->unique.erase(currentShare.begin(), currentShare.end());
        p->shared.insert(currentShare.begin(), currentShare.end());
        data->shared.insert(currentShare.begin(), currentShare.end());
        p = p->next;
    }
    currentShare = setIntersection(p->unique, data->unique);
    for (it = currentShare.begin(); it != currentShare.end(); ++it)
    {
        p->unique.erase(*it);
        p->shared.insert(*it);
        data->shared.insert(*it);
    }

    currentSolution.insert(s);
    kSetUnion.insert(data->S.begin(), data->S.end());

    if (*rear != NULL)
        (*rear)->next = data;
    else
        *front = data;
    *rear = data;
}
```

This function is called from this other function

`set<set<string>> maxSMod(set<set<string>> &F, set<string> U, int k)`

important segment:

```
    Node *front = NULL, *rear = NULL, *p;
    set<set<string>>::iterator it = F.begin();
    set<string> kSetsUnion;
    set<set<string>> currentSolution;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        solution.insert(*it);
        refreshOnDataEntry(*it, &front, &rear, currentSolution, kSetsUnion);
        ++it;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the error, but accessing `p` after ` while (p!=NULL)` will result in undefined behaviour. After that loop `p` is `NULL`. Btw. in C++ you should prefer `nullptr`.

Comment: Since you use std::set. std::string, why aren't you using std::list? That way you can avoid having to use those pointers (something recommended in the C++ core guidelines anyway).

Comment: Not familiar with the library but willing to bet one of those functions invalidates your pointer. Then your pointer isn't null, but it is just rubbish, hence it crashes

Comment: If only you had included the value of `p` in your tracing messages...

Comment: All of this usage of STL you currently are doing, and as mentioned, all of those pointers could simply be `std::list<Node>` and remove the `next` member (and `prev` member, if it exists).  Then this: `while (p!=NULL)` becomes a simple loop iterating through the `std::list`, without any pointer manipulation going on.

Comment: I have no clue what this function is supposed to do and what is the problem statement you are trying to solve. Also, this is not a [mre].